# Index and Match formula with multiple Lookup Values but for one cell

Tags: excel, match

Im looking for some help with a formula for Index and Match.

```
=INDEX(F$2:AE$2,MATCH(1,F20:AE20,0))
```

This formula will match the 1st cell that has a number 1. But I also want it to look and count if the cell has either a 1, OT, or TR. And then pull the corresponding value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, looks like you can just use COUNTIF to count both three matches and wrap them in a SUM function to have your results. Or maybe your problem is a more complicated one, which I think we'll need some pics of your sheet and desired output to properly help.

Comment: Hi, I tried a nested IF formula with countif is more than 0, but it will give me whatever the 1st IF is. Which is not always the case. What would your suggestion look like as a formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
=INDEX(F$2:AE$2,MIN(IFERROR(MATCH(1,F20:AE20,0),9999),IFERROR(MATCH("OT",F20:AE20,0),9999),IFERROR(MATCH("TR",F20:AE20,0),9999)))
```

It should return the header associated with the first occurrence of either ***1*** or ***OT*** or ***TR***

**Note:**

There is a much simplier formula, but it is an array formula.